# Floating Snapshot while reading a document

Tags: software-recommendation

You may have come across a situation while reading a document, wherein the author refers an image in page 100 while you are in page 200.

I would like to have an application that allows me to take a snapshot and keep it floating above the document viewer side by side for reference.

I tried to use [windowspy](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/?p=114927), but the visibility level is not just enough to read small fonts in the image file if you take a snapshot and keep it in another workspace.

Is there any alternative application to satisfy my requirements?

Comment: [shutter](http://shutter-project.org/)? In edit mode you can see the shot in full resolution, and even mark/highlight things.

Comment: I do use shutter, but it does not float on top of a document viewer. In a nutshell, I prefer an image frame of zero edge frame-width that floats above any documentation editor.